# Disable a Share link for wall post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, postmessage

I am developing an application that will be posted on the wall of the private Facebook Group by using Open Graph. If I have a general post in this group there is no view of the "Share" link, but with Open Graph it is. What I need is to disable the possibility to "Share" this post out from this group, e.g. disable "Share" link under the post. Is it possible to implement such behavior via Open Graph API? Or any other solutions?

Comment: hmm..are you able to see the Share link ? Per my understanding, closed groups don't have the ability to Share posts. It's related to permission settings.